# What types of swiss army cards can you take onboard a plane for international travel?

Tags: luggage, safety, hand-luggage

I have had trouble before trying to buy the Tool Logic card which contains a blade with serrated edge because it was held up by customs in Australia, which makes it obvious that it is unsuitable for both check-in or carry-on luggage when traveling.

However, it appears that there are types of swiss army cards that may have tools which are deemed to be safe to carry on planes when travelling internationally. Just wondering if anyone has done so before or have had experiences to share about these types of gadgets?

As per the comment, I am thinking mainly between Australia and USA as the destinations. If there is a lot of different between the laws for different countries I will put up another questions for those specific countries.

Comment: Knives and other weapons are generally permitted in checked luggage; the problems occur at the destination country. To answer the question, we would need to know where you're going.

Comment: @Michael Hampton: might this be a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68639/able-to-carry-on-a-small-swiss-army-knife

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checked: any one that you like.

Carry-on: nothing with a knife/knife-like/blade for [Australia](http://travelsecure.infrastructure.gov.au/onboard/what-i-cannot-take-onboard.aspx/). [In the US](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/prohibited-items), you can generally get away with something that has a blade less than 4".

Practical: I commuted between Sydney and USA (Texas) every 6 - 8 weeks for three years, making dozens of trips. I had a Swiss Army Card with the file attachment removed. About 18 months into traveling, Australian airport security confiscated it, on the basis that the (very, very small) scissors blade represented a weapon.

All of the [Swiss Cards](https://www.swissarmy.com/us/en/Products/Swiss-Army-Knives/SwissCards/c/SAK_SwissCard) have a blade, scissor, or blade-like implement. Your only option would be to check it or selectively remove items prior to traveling with it as your carry-on. Otherwise you risk having it confiscated. However, there's at least a decent chance you'll get away with it.